# Using flexbox, can I have 1 fixed-width column and 1 column that takes the rest of the width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Currently I have something similar to the code below. I'm trying to make the red column irresponsive with set width of 300px but keep the responsiveness of the blue column.

```css
.specific-image-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.specific-image-column {
    flex: 4;
    background-color: blue;
}
.more-images-column {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="specific-image-container">

    <div class="specific-image-column">
        <div class='content'></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="more-images-column">
        <div class='content'></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, set the fixed column to `flex-grow: 0` (so it doesn't grow), `flex-shrink: 0` (so it doesn't shrink), and `flex-basis: 300px` (so it stays fixed at 300px).

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fa5e9Ltk/4/)

```css
.specific-image-container {
    display: flex;
}
.specific-image-column {
    flex: 1;
    background-color: blue;
}
.more-images-column {
    flex: 0 0 300px; /* new */
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="specific-image-container">

  <div class="specific-image-column">
    <div class='content'></div>
  </div>

  <div class="more-images-column">
    <div class='content'></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: @michael there is already too many dupes on this one ;)

Comment: okay @dippas.. you are right..  I should have looked around first

Answer (score 2):

Set `flex-shrink: 0; width: 300px;` on the irresponsive element, and `flex-grow: 1;` on the flexible element. You can get rid of the `flex` property once you’ve done that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `flex-basis` rule. You can use this rule in place of width in flexbox elements. You can also use calc to set the first column to 100% - 300px to make sure 300px takes priority.

```css
.specific-image-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.specific-image-column {
    flex-basis: calc(100% - 300px);
    background-color: blue;
}
.more-images-column {
    flex-basis: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="specific-image-container">

    <div class="specific-image-column">
        <div class='content'></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="more-images-column">
        <div class='content'></div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```